# Dynamic TimePicker Dialog in android

Tags: android, timepicker

I had a requirement for making a dynamic time picker dialog in android. Basically the time changes every time I pick a date from calendar and the range has to change each time. Thus, it means suppose in date 4/5/2017, the time range is from 9-2 the minimum value has to be 9 and maximum has to be 2 with a increment of 1.
Till now what I have done is just set a time picker dialog

```
private void calltimerange() {
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        final TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
              //  Toast.makeText(context, "" + selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvTime.setText(String.valueOf(selectedHour));
                mytime = String.valueOf(selectedHour);
            }

        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use if you want in easy way :

[MaterialDateTimePicker by wdullaer](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

and look for this feature:

- **setMinTime(Timepoint time)**

  Set the minimum valid time to be selected. Time values earlier in the day will 
  be deactivated
- **setMaxTime(Timepoint time)**

  Set the maximum valid time to be selected. Time values later in the day will be 
  deactivated
- **setSelectableTimes(Timepoint[] times)**

  You can pass in an array of Timepoints. These values are the only valid 
  selections in the picker. setMinTime(Timepoint time) and setMaxTime(Timepoint 
  time) will further trim this list down.

Comment: Thanks, but I was in favor of not using a library for this task. I was seeking for a answer that does not use a library.

Comment: Even the library is not syncing in my apps gradle. I am getting errors. What else do I need to have for this library?

Comment: What is the error? Can't tell without looking into it.

Comment: It needs design and support libraries-v 25, mine versions are 24. Cannot update to that

Comment: If that is so then, why don't you use this :                             
                                                                                             
                TimePickerDialog (Context context, 
                 int themeResId, 
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, 
                int hourOfDay, //your minimum and maximum date respectively 
                int minute, 
                boolean is24HourView)

Comment: It would be great i you could elaborate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
private void editTextDatePicker() {

    final EditText et_datepicker = new EditText(this);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    et_datepicker.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    et_datepicker.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
    et_datepicker.setHint("Pick your Date");
    et_datepicker.setFocusable(false);
    et_datepicker.setGravity(1);
    et_datepicker.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_background);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.dialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            et_datepicker.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    et_datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datepicker.show();
        }
    });
    linerLayoutChild.addView(et_datepicker); // here lineaLayoutChild is the object for your layout where you want to add. 
}
```

Comment: the above code i used for datepicker and it works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I need it for time picker, which is to be dynamic. Please go through my question again.

Comment: yes i have gone through your code both have the same code just change simple date formate to
 SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
 
instead of getting year month 
 newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

use
 newCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), newCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));